# How can I implement real time queries in strapi?

Tags: javascript, github, mean-stack, strapi

I'm planning to use strapi in production and also wanted to use realtime query.please help me with that.

Comment: Hello! Can you please precise your need please.
I'm not sure to follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: hey @JimLAURIE thanks for response.I want use real-time queries in my app i.e the changes made in database should be reflected on the front end at the same time it is very similar to to real-time feature provided by hasura here [https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/subscriptions/index.html#execution]